# Excel scientific notation converting numeric value to E+ characters

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, numeric, scientific-notation

Excel scientific notation converting numeric value to E+ characters. How to handle this in excel parcing in c#? im expecting it as string value.for example my input is '123456789012345678901234567890' but excel automatically convert it to 1.23456789012345E+29.

im expecting it came as string value or need a solution to convert it to string in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the below code snippet

```
var exampleString ="1.23456789012345E+29";
var result = BigInteger.Parse(exampleString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any).ToString();
```

Hope this will work for you..

Comment: The original value is **`35698216547798`**. In scientific notation, it appears as **`3.56982E+13`**. However, after parsing with your code, the obtained value is **`35698200000000`**, which is incorrect!